# Recover data from two classes into many to many

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many, symfony5

I have a User table and a Library table, the relationship between them are many to many.

So I have a `user_library` table.

I manage to add data to the Library table from User but I cannot recover the data afterwards.

I add them like this:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repoUser = $em->getRepository('App:User');
    $user = $repoUser->findOneBy(['token' => $token_user]);

    $library = new Library();
    $library->setIdBook($id_book);

    $user->addLibrary($library);
    $em->persist($library);
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
```

I thought that simply doing: `$user->getLibrary()->getIdBook()` would be enough but it is not the case.

How do you think I can get all the `id_book` that match the `user`?

Comment: Something does not make sense here. If the relationship is "ManyToMany", which library would `getLibrary()` fetch? Wouldn't that be a collection? And how could a collection have an id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that your getLibrary returns ArrayCollection, you need to specify which Library you exactly want

```
$libararies = $user->getLibrary() // <- this returns ArrayCollection
$library = $libraries->first() // <- return 1st element
```

Based on this code you can do a search for example, or just use doctrine to fetch library with desired ID, user, whatever you need straight from the database
**EDIT**
Lets say you want all libraries that are in relation with user with ID = 4

```
... // your code
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('your user class')->find(4); // here we find your user from DB
$libraries = $user->getLibrary() // here we get all libraries which are in relation with user #4, you might want to rename the function as it returns ArrayCollection of Libraries, not Library
$bookIds = array();
foreach($libraries as $library) {
    $bookIds[] = $library->getIdBook(); 
}
dump($bookIds); // all user #4 book ids
die;
```

Comment: your method return only the first element.
How to return all elements who correspond at my user?

Also, when a user add the same data, this data is added to the database.
I'm putting screenshots for you so you can understand.

[My table User][1]

[My table User_Library][2]

[My table Libray][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTOjV.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElZl8.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqJiu.png

Comment: Editted my answer, give it a try